# How do I install Nexus 3 in a Docker container with no internet connection?

Tags: linux, windows, docker, repository, nexus

I want to install Nexus 3 in a Docker container on CentOS.  But my CentOS server with Docker installed on it has no access to the internet.  I want to use this command:

Docker pull sonatype/nexus3

Is there a standalone, offline file or group of files to give me what I need?

I have only Windows machines with no Docker installed that can access the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and setup your own Docker registry server on your windows machine and then have your centos server talk to that server to get the files that it needs. This seems like overkill though.

Here is the link to set that up: https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/

You could also use something like virtualbox and create a centos server and then setup docker in there on the windows machine. This would allow you to have centos + docker + internet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can save the image to a file and then load it on the server:

1. Download the image to your workstation with `docker pull sonatype/nexus3`
2. Save the image to a tar file with `docker save sonatype/nexus3 > nexus3.tar` - [Docs Save Docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/)
3. Transfer the image to the server via USB/LAN/etc
4. Import the image on the CentOS server with `docker load --input nexus3.tar` - [Docker Load Docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/)

**Docker Save**

> Produces a tarred repository to the standard output stream. Contains all parent layers, and all tags + versions, or specified `repo:tag`, for each argument provided.

**Docker Load**

> Loads a tarred repository from a file or the standard input stream. Restores both images and tags.

You will now have the image loaded on your machine. There are probably other ways, but this is the simplest I can think of and involves no 3rd party tools. You can also `gzip` the file, per the documentation.

Comment: I'd rather not have to have Docker installed on my Windows workstation.  Is there any way around that?

Comment: You can use any workstation or server that has Docker installed to pull down the image. You could even use a virtual machine running on Virtualbox or VMware on your Windows workstation, to keep your host machine clean.